# How can I recover my old Facebook account?

Tags: facebook

I had a Facebook account, but I forgot my password. When I created a new account using the same mobile number, I could no longer recover my old Facebook account.

I don't have an email account. I created my account by mobile number, so how can I recover my old Facebook account at this point?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to enter your phone number on the [Account Recovery Page](https://www.facebook.com/recover.php), which allows you to identify your accounts and reset your password.

Source: [How To Recover Your Facebook Account When You Can No Longer Log In](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/recover-facebook-account-longer-log/)

Comment: Given source link is broken.

Comment: Fixed @serenesat

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new account will not give you option to recover your old account or reset the password. If you forgot the password, you should follow the steps to reset the password.

> [**How do I reset my password?**](https://www.facebook.com/help/213395615347144):
>
> If you can't log into Facebook and need to reset your password:
>
> 1. Go to the Facebook login screen at https://www.facebook.com/
> 2. In the top right, click **Forgot your password?**
> 3. Type the email, phone number, full name or username associated with your account, then click **Search** and follow the on-screen instructions